# C++ Random Number Generation: Generate cos squared function

Tags: c++, c++11, random, probability, probability-density

The probability distribution of interest is

```
double x; // range: -pi/2.0 to +pi/2.0
double y = std::pow(std::cos(x), 2.0);
```

This function can be integrated analytically, however it cannot be inverted. Therefore the usual trick of mapping a uniform distribution to the required probability distribution cannot be performed.

Is there another method which can be used to generate a random variable cos^2(theta) distribution?

It may be possible to find the inverse function numerically, however I do not know of an efficient (memory and computationally) method of doing this.

Comment: Is rejection sampling acceptable?

Comment: This can't be the distribution - its integral over the range isn't equal to 1. It could be salvaged if you scale it by `2/pi`. To save someone the trouble, the cumulative distribution function for this case is `F(x) = (x + sin(2*x)/2 + pi/2) / pi`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Good point - I did not normalize it as the normalization depends on the range of x - since I wrote this I decided it was probably easier to use the range 0 to pi/2.0, rather than the original range specified in the question.

Answer (score 3):

From [Inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling): you can generate sample numbers at random from any probability distribution, given its cdf.

Say you want cos<sup>2</sup>x distribution, from -pi/2 to pi/2. Since integral of cos<sup>2</sup>x from -pi/2 to pi/2 is pi/2, you need to scale down so that the integral is 1. Thus, the pdf P(x) = (2/pi)cos<sup>2</sup>x

Next step is calculate cdf from given pdf, which is the pdf's integral. You can use any numerical method to find integral of P(x). Or you can go to Wolfram Alpha and get the answer: cdf is F(x) = (2/pi)(0.5x + 0.25sin2x) + 0.5

Next you need to calcluate F<sup>-1</sup>(x). Since F(x) is a monotonically increasing function, you can use bisection method (binary search) to find F<sup>-1</sup>(x) easily. Wolfram Alpha doesn't have this F<sup>-1</sup>(x) formula though.

Then generate a uniform real number u from 0 to 1. Your custom distribution is F<sup>-1</sup>(u).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <boost/random/random_device.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

const double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;

const double LOW = -pi/2;
const double HIGH = pi/2;
double pdf(double x)
{
    return cos(x) * cos(x);
}

double cdf(double x) //integral of pdf
{
    return (2/pi)*(x/2 + sin(2*x)/4) + 0.5; //from Wolfram Alpha
}

double inverse_cdf(double u)
{   //bisection, not 100% accurate
    double low  = LOW;
    double high = HIGH;
    double epsilon = 1e-10; //any small number, e.g. 1e-15
    while (high - low > epsilon)
    {
        double mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (cdf(mid) == u) return mid;
        if (cdf(mid) < u) low = mid; else high = mid;
    }
    return (low + high) / 2;
}

double custom_distribution(std::mt19937& rng)
{
    double u = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0,1)(rng);
    return inverse_cdf(u);
}

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 rng{boost::random::random_device{}()};

    std::vector<double> xCount(15);
    int nSamples = 10000;
    double gap = (HIGH-LOW) / xCount.size();
    while (nSamples--) xCount[(int)( (custom_distribution(rng) - LOW) / gap )]++;
    for (int i = 0; i < xCount.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << i << ":" << xCount[i] << "\t";
        for (int bar = xCount[i]/15; bar--; std::cout << '*');
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

sample output:

```
 0:17   *
 1:135  *********
 2:305  ********************
 3:604  ****************************************
 4:859  *********************************************************
 5:1106 *************************************************************************
 6:1256 ***********************************************************************************
 7:1353 ******************************************************************************************
 8:1271 ************************************************************************************
 9:1102 *************************************************************************
10:876  **********************************************************
11:614  ****************************************
12:334  **********************
13:143  *********
14:25   *
```